# Why is the absolute error estimate of my integral greater than the integral (using scipy.integrate.nquad)?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm trying to evaluate this 5-fold integral

[image]

where `a`, `w`, `t`, `x1`, `x2` are constants and `y1(x)`, `y2(x)` are non-constant integration bounds of `y` that depend on `x`. I can evaluate them all, and then I compute the integral using `nquad` function of `scipy.integrate` as follows:

```
from scipy.integrate import nquad
from math import sqrt

               # UNIT
a = 2.0        # unitless
w = 100e-9     # meter
t = 20e-9      # meter
delta = 20e-9  # meter (used to calculate x1, x2, y1, y2)

def integrand(y_prime, z_prime, y, x, z):
    num = (-1/2)*((x-a*w/2) + sqrt(3)*(y-y_prime))
    den = ((x-a*w/2)**2 + (y-y_prime)**2 + (z-z_prime)**2)**(3/2)
    return num/den

# integration bounds of x
x1 = (1/2)*(a*w + 3*delta)
x2 = (1/2)*(w*(a + sqrt(3)) + 3*delta)

# integration bounds of y
def y1(x):
    m1 = -1/sqrt(3)
    n1 = (1/2)*(w*(a/sqrt(3) + 1) + delta*(1 + sqrt(3)))
    return m1*x + n1
def y2(x):
    m2 = sqrt(3)
    n2 = (1/2)*(w*(1 - a*sqrt(3)) + delta*(1 - 3*sqrt(3)))
    return m2*x + n2

integral = nquad(integrand,
                 [[-w/2, w/2],                  # y' bounds
                  [0, t],                       # z' bounds
                  lambda x, z: [y1(x), y2(x)],  # y bounds
                  [x1, x2],                     # x bounds
                  [0, t]])                      # z bounds

print(integral)
```

The output is `(-2.3258337548893193e-23, 0.42437932862557626)`.

I have good reasons to believe that the value `-2.3258337548893193e-23` is correct (at least, the order of magnitude is as expected). However, I'm worried about the extremely large value of `0.42437932862557626` of the absolute error estimate since it is not only larger than the integral, but it exceeds it by 22 orders of magnitude!

I tried to play of several ways with the `epsabs` and `epsrel` optional parameters to improve the error estimate (e.g., as suggested by [this article](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/03/20/scipy-integration/)), but none of them worked properly: the better I could achieve was an error estimate of `2.7568352154734943e-06` with the same value for the integral.

My last try was to change the values of my constant parameters, that happen to be physical lengths. So, instead of setting their values in meters, I set them in *nano*meters:

```
               # UNIT
a = 2.0        # unitless
w = 100        # nanometer
t = 20         # nanometer
delta = 20     # nanometer (used to calculate x1, x2, y1, y2)
```

Inspecting the integral, this change should only scale its value by a factor of `(1e9)**3=1e27` (and then if I want its value with lengths expressed in meters I just have to *divide* it by `1e27`). And, indeed, the output is `(-23258.337548893207, 1.0567318670726077e-06)`, with the value of the integral rescaled as expected. Even better, the error didn't scale along and has an acceptable value now!

Although I have apparently circumvented my problem, I'm still wondering if I could achieve the good result using parameters expressed in meters. Or, at least understand why the error is so large in the first case but not in the second one. It seems that has to be with the particular value of the integral: when it is "large" the error is comparatively small, but when it is "small" the error is comparatively large.

Comment: Numerical computations are usually more stable when their values are on the order of magnitude `1`. The result you get is even smaller than the floating point epsilon. But in any case, the default value for the absolute error tolerance (`epsabs`) is `1.49e-8` which is way larger than your expected result, so you could try setting this to zero.

Comment: @a_guest That was one of the things I tried, but, as I said, I could reduce the error only to about `1e-6`. I didn't know about this rule of thumb concerning order of magnitude of the value of the integral, so thank you. In the end, my final resolution was exactly a manipulation to scale the original, small value to one closer to `1`.